# Lazy evaluation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lazy-evaluation

What is lazy evaluation in Python?

One website said :

In Python 3.x the `range()` function returns a special range object which computes elements of the list on demand (lazy or deferred evaluation):

```
>>> r = range(10)
>>> print(r)
range(0, 10)
>>> print(r[3])
3
```

What is meant by this?

Comment: Create a generator (e.g. `def` containing `yield`) that causes a side-effect like `print` before it yields a value. Then loop the generator with a one-second delay each iteration. When do the prints occur? Python 3's `range` (much like `xrange` in Python 2) works about like that: the computations are not done until asked. This is what "lazy evaluation" means.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The object returned by `range()` (or `xrange()` in Python2.x) is known as a lazy iterable.

Instead of storing the entire range, `[0,1,2,..,9]`, in memory, the generator stores a definition for `(i=0; i<10; i+=1)` and computes the next value only when needed (AKA lazy-evaluation).

Essentially, a generator allows you to return a list like structure, but here are some differences:

1. A list stores all elements when it is created. A generator generates the next element when it is needed.
2. A list can be iterated over as much as you need, a generator can only be iterated over *exactly* once.
3. A list can get elements by index, a generator cannot -- it only generates values once, from start to end.

**A generator can be created in two ways:**

(1) Very similar to a list comprehension:

```
# this is a list, create all 5000000 x/2 values immediately, uses []
lis = [x/2 for x in range(5000000)]

# this is a generator, creates each x/2 value only when it is needed, uses ()
gen = (x/2 for x in range(5000000))
```

(2) As a function, using `yield` to return the next value:

```
# this is also a generator, it will run until a yield occurs, and return that result.
# on the next call it picks up where it left off and continues until a yield occurs...
def divby2(n):
    num = 0
    while num < n:
        yield num/2
        num += 1

# same as (x/2 for x in range(5000000))
print divby2(5000000)
```

**Note:** Even though `range(5000000)` is a generator in Python3.x, `[x/2 for x in range(5000000)]` is still a list. `range(...)` does it's job and generates `x` one at a time, but the entire list of `x/2` values will be computed when this list is create.

Comment: Actually, `range` (or `xrange` in 2.x) does *not* return a generator. A generator is an iterator -- for any generator `g` you can call `next(g)`. A `range` object is actually an iterable. You can call `iter` on it to get an iterator, but it is not an iterator itself (you can't call `next` on it). Among other things, this means that you can iterate over a single range object multiple times.

Comment: "a generator can only be iterated over exactly once." isn't true. You can iterate less than once by using next(), breaking out of a for loop, or simply not accessing it at all. Perhaps remove the word "exactly" or change it to "at most".

Comment: @LaurenceGonsalves I edited the answer to correct the matter.

Answer (score 22):

In a nutshell, lazy evaluation means that the object is evaluated when it is needed, not when it is created.

In Python 2, range will return a list - this means that if you give it a large number, it will calculate the range and return at the time of creation:

```
>>> i = range(100)
>>> type(i)
<type 'list'>
```

In Python 3, however you get a special range object:

```
>>> i = range(100)
>>> type(i)
<class 'range'>
```

Only when you consume it, will it actually be evaluated - in other words, it will only return the numbers in the range when you actually need them.

Answer (score 11):

A github repo named [python patterns](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/patterns/creational/lazy_evaluation.py#L19) and [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation) tell us what lazy evaluation is.

> Delays the eval of an expr until its value is needed and avoids repeated evals.

`range` in python3 is not a complete lazy evaluation, because it doesn't avoid repeated eval.

A more classic example for lazy evaluation is `cached_property`:

```
import functools

class cached_property(object):
    def __init__(self, function):
        self.function = function
        functools.update_wrapper(self, function)

    def __get__(self, obj, type_):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        val = self.function(obj)
        obj.__dict__[self.function.__name__] = val
        return val
```

The cached_property(a.k.a lazy_property) is a decorator which convert a func into a lazy evaluation property. The first time property accessed, the func is called to get result and then the value is used the next time you access the property.

eg:

```
class LogHandler:
    def __init__(self, file_path):
        self.file_path = file_path

    @cached_property
    def load_log_file(self):
        with open(self.file_path) as f:
            # the file is to big that I have to cost 2s to read all file
            return f.read()

log_handler = LogHandler('./sys.log')
# only the first time call will cost 2s.
print(log_handler.load_log_file)
# return value is cached to the log_handler obj.
print(log_handler.load_log_file)
```

To use a proper word, a python generator object like *range* are more like designed through **call_by_need** pattern, rather than **lazy evaluation**

Comment: As of 2018, the Wikipedia article treats "call by need" and "lazy evaluation" as synonyms. Because the Python 3 version of `range()` does indeed not create a whole list of numbers but instead generates numbers until we stop requesting one (e.g. by breaking a for loop), it _is_ indeed (sic) "delaying the eval of  an expr until its value is needed". I'd say you're wrong to treat them as two different concepts.

Comment: You need i when you excute type(i), not when you excute i=range(100).
I would say Vi.Ci is correct.

Comment: link to patterns repo moved to https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/patterns/creational/lazy_evaluation.py