# Faster and more consise way to reverse sentences in a string?

Tags: python, string, algorithm

Okay, I am looking for a way to reverse sentences in a string in a fast and concise manner.

For example, if I wanted to convert "“One two three. Four five six.” to “Three two one. Six five four.”

Here's my naive approach:

```
def reverse_sentences(str):
 newlist=str.split(".")   
 newstr=''
 for s in newlist[0:-1]:
   words=s.split()
   words=words[::-1]
   words[0]=words[0][0].upper()+words[0][1:]
   words[-1]=words[-1][0].lower()+words[-1][1:]
   for e in range(len(words)):
      words[e].strip()
      if words[e] != words[-1]:
           newstr+=words[e]+" "
      else:
           newstr+=words[e]
   newstr+=". "
 return newstr
```

Any faster and more Pythonic way to do this, e.g. list comprehensions and stuff.

Comment: what if the input is `One, two three.`? How do you deal with `,`?

Comment: Not sure, assume only periods exist and not commas. It would be an interesting solution though if one could figure that out precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably write something like this using [generator expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) (for [lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20535342/78845)):

```
def reverse_sentences(text):
    sentences = text.split('.')
    reversed_words = (reversed(words.split()) for words in sentences)
    rejoined_words = (' '.join(words) for words in reversed_words)
    capitalized_sentences = (sentence.capitalize() for sentence in rejoined_words)
    return '. '.join(capitalized_sentences)

reverse_sentences("One two three. Four five six.")
```

I prefer this function over a "one-liner", since it's easier to maintain (for instance, should you wish to add handling for punctuation, or [`strip`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip)-ping whitespace).

Breaking this down into its component parts (using [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) for illustration):

```
In [1]: text = "One two three. Four five six."

In [2]: text
Out[2]: 'One two three. Four five six.'

In [3]: sentences = text.split('.')

In [4]: sentences
Out[4]: ['One two three', ' Four five six', '']

In [5]: reversed_words = [words.split()[::-1] for words in sentences]

In [6]: reversed_words
Out[6]: [['three', 'two', 'One'], ['six', 'five', 'Four'], []]

In [7]: rejoined_words= [' '.join(words) for words in reversed_words]

In [8]: rejoined_words
Out[8]: ['three two One', 'six five Four', '']

In [9]: capitalized_sentences = [sentence.capitalize() for sentence in rejoined_words]

In [10]: capitalized_sentences
Out[10]: ['Three two one', 'Six five four', '']

In [11]: '. '.join(capitalized_sentences)
Out[11]: 'Three two one. Six five four. '
```

### Note:

- [`reversed()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reversed) returns an [`iterator`](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator), so I used the less efficient but easier to demonstrate [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/q/509211/78845) in the illustration.

## Speed

You probably want to know *how fast* this runs...

[`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is handy here.

### [Your example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22109485/78845)

```
> python -m timeit <<EOF
def reverse_sentences(str):
 newlist=str.split(".")
 newstr=''
 for s in newlist[0:-1]:
   words=s.split()
   words=words[::-1]
   words[0]=words[0][0].upper()+words[0][1:]
   words[-1]=words[-1][0].lower()+words[-1][1:]
   for e in range(len(words)):
      words[e].strip()
      if words[e] != words[-1]:
           newstr+=words[e]+" "
      else:
           newstr+=words[e]
   newstr+=". "
 return newstr

reverse_sentences("One two three. Four five six.")
EOF
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.012 usec per loop
```

### [My example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22109584/78845)

```
> python -m timeit <<EOF
def reverse_sentences(text):     
    sentences = text.split('.')                                                                      
    reversed_words = (reversed(words.split()) for words in sentences)
    rejoined_words = (' '.join(words) for words in reversed_words)
    capitalized_sentences = (sentence.capitalize() for sentence in rejoined_words)
    return '. '.join(capitalized_sentences)

reverse_sentences("One two three. Four five six.")
EOF
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.012 usec per loop
```

### [zhangxaochen's example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22109520/78845)

```
> python -m timeit <<EOF
t="One two three. Four five six."
' '.join(' '.join(sentence.lower().split()[::-1]).capitalize()+'.' for sentence in t.split('.')[:-1])
EOF                                                                  
100000000 loops, best of 3: 0.012 usec per loop
```

## Conclusion

Optimise for readability and maintainability by adhering to [The Zen of Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/) and your code will be "more pythonic".

Comment: There's a capitalize function in Python?! Wow thanks for this!

Comment: @garlfd: [`str.capitalize()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.capitalize), yes!

Comment: and maybe apply strip() to the final result to get rid of the extra space at the end?

Comment: @lessthanl0l: Yup. Lots of tweaks that can be made. My answer is all about *the approach*.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a long one-liner using *list comprehension* and *slicing* and `str.join`:

```
In [79]: t="One two three. Four five six."

In [80]: ' '.join(' '.join(sentence.lower().split()[::-1]).capitalize()+'.'
    ...:                              for sentence in t.split('.')[:-1])
Out[80]: 'Three two one. Six five four.'
```

Comment:  This is certainly "more concise", which is what was asked for. It doesn't appear to be faster (see my answer) or more Pythonic (see [PEP 20](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/)), but I do like your functional approach.

Comment: @Johnsyweb yes it's not faster, just for fun ;)