# Does range() really create lists?

Tags: python, range

Both my professor and [this guy](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/lambda_functions.hawk) claim that `range` creates a list of values.

> "Note: The range function simply returns a list containing the numbers
>   from x to y-1. For example, range(5, 10) returns the list [5, 6, 7, 8,
>   9]."

I believe this is to be inaccurate because:

```
type(range(5, 10))
<class 'range'>
```

Furthermore, the only apparent way to access the integers created by `range` is to iterate through them, which leads me to believe that labeling `range` as a lists is incorrect.

Comment: Your last sentence is incorrect.  `range` objects implement `__getitem__`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Lazy evaluation python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535342/lazy-evaluation-python)

Comment: This question is not aware of the differences between Python 2 and 3, and is *not* a dupe of the one linked.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you always favor xrange() over range()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/135041/should-you-always-favor-xrange-over-range)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

In Python 2.x, [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) returns a list, but in Python 3.x [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) returns an immutable sequence, of type [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range).

**Python 2.x:**

```
>>> type(range(10))
<type 'list'>
>>> type(xrange(10))
<type 'xrange'>
```

**Python 3.x:**

```
>>> type(range(10))
<class 'range'>
```

In Python 2.x, if you want to get an iterable object, like in Python 3.x, you can use [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#xrange) function, which returns an immutable sequence of type [`xrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-xrange).

Advantage of `xrange` over `range` in Python 2.x:

> The advantage of `xrange()` over `range()` is minimal (since `xrange()` still has to create the values when asked for them) except when a very large range is used on a memory-starved machine or when all of the range’s elements are never used (such as when the loop is usually terminated with break).

**Note:**

> Furthermore, the only apparent way to access the integers created by `range()` is to iterate through them,

Nope. Since `range` objects in Python 3 are immutable sequences, they support indexing as well. Quoting from the `range` function documentation,

> Ranges implement all of the common sequence operations except concatenation and repetition
>
> ...
>
> Range objects implement the [`collections.abc.Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sequence) ABC, and provide features such as containment tests, **element index lookup**, slicing and support for negative indices.

For example,

```
>>> range(10, 20)[5]
15
>>> range(10, 20)[2:5]
range(12, 15)
>>> list(range(10, 20)[2:5])
[12, 13, 14]
>>> list(range(10, 20, 2))
[10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
>>> 18 in range(10, 20)
True
>>> 100 in range(10, 20)
False
```

All these are possible with that immutable `range` sequence.

---

Recently, I faced a problem and I think it would be appropriate to include here. Consider this Python 3.x code

```
from itertools import islice
numbers = range(100)
items = list(islice(numbers, 10))
while items:
    items = list(islice(numbers, 10))
    print(items)
```

One would expect this code to print every ten numbers as a list, till 99. But, it would run infinitely. Can you reason why?

**Solution**

> Because the `range` returns an immutable *sequence*, not an iterator object. So, whenever `islice` is done on a `range` object, it always starts from the beginning. Think of it as a drop-in replacement for an immutable list. Now the question comes, how will you fix it? Its simple, you just have to get an iterator out of it. Simply change
>
>         `numbers = range(100)`
>
>  to
>
>         `numbers = iter(range(100))`
>
>  Now, `numbers` is an iterator object and it remembers how long it has been iterated before. So, when the `islice` iterates it, it just starts from the place where it previously ended.

Comment: It returns a `range` object that happens to be iterable, but is more than a plain iterator :) (eg: `range(1, 100, 17)[3]` is perfectly legal)

Comment: @JonClements Thanks, updated the answer with the information about `range` and `xrange` objects :-)

Comment: unrelated: `x in range(large_number)` in Python 3 may use an optimized implementation that doesn't iterate over the range.

Comment: To highlight a key point: unlike `list`, the python 3.x `range` is lazy and does not occupy memory for every element in the range.

Answer (score 8):

**It depends.**

In python-2.x, `range` actually creates a list (which is also a sequence) whereas `xrange` creates an `xrange` object that can be used to iterate through the values.

On the other hand, in python-3.x, `range` creates an iterable (or more specifically, a sequence)

Comment: There's no "sort of" about it - `range()` in python 3 returns an iterable, `import collections; isinstance(range(2), collections.Iterable)` is True (and to nitpick - don't use the heading syntax for emphasis - if you really need to, bold is more appropriate)

Comment: @dbr: it is a bit more complex than just an iterable, though.

Comment: range object is not an [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator), it is an [iterable](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterable) (more specifically it is a [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence)).

Comment: note: list is a sequence i.e., `range()` returns sequences on both Python 2 and 3

Answer (score 2):

range creates a list if the python version used is 2.x .
In this scenario range is to be used only if its referenced more than once otherwise use xrange which creates a generator there by redusing the memory usage  and sometimes time as it has lazy approach.

xrange is not there in python 3.x rather range stands for what xrange is for python 2.x

refer to question
 [What is the difference between range and xrange functions in Python 2.X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/94935/what-is-the-difference-between-range-and-xrange)

Answer (score 0):

### Python3

##### `for` loop with `range` function

To understand what `for i in range()` means in Python3, we need first to understand the working of the `range()` function.

The `range()` function uses the generator to produce numbers. **It doesn’t generate all numbers at once.**

As you know `range()` returns the `range` object. A `range` object **uses the same (small) amount of memory**, no matter the size of the range it represents. It only stores the start, stop and step values and calculates individual items and subranges as needed.

I.e., It generates the next value only when `for` loop iteration asked for it. In each loop iteration, It generates the next value and assigns it to the iterator variable `i`.

***So it means `range()` produces numbers one by one as the loop moves to the next iteration.** It saves lots of memory, which makes range() faster and efficient.*

**Reference**: [PyNative - for loop with range()](https://pynative.com/python-range-function/#h-for-loop-with-range)