# Is there a built-in function for creating a list of random numbers of size 'n'?

Tags: python, list, random

The standard way of creating a list of random numbers is:

```
def generateList(n):
    randlist = []
    for i in range(n):
        randlist.append(random.randint(1,9))
    return randlist
```

However, I recently stumbled upon `random.sample`, which is much more compact:

```
def generateList(n):
    return random.sample(range(1, 10), n)
```

But this results in an error if `n` is greater than 10. So, my question is, does there exist a built-in function that does exactly what I intend it to do without running into error? If not, is there at least a more efficient alternative to the first excerpt (considering that `n` can be quite large)?

Comment: You are misinterpreting `random.sample`: notice that none of the numbers in the random list ever appears twice. A shorter version of `generateList` is `lambda n: [randint(1,9) for _ in range(n)]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The activity of sampling is to select a maximum of `N` elements from the sample space of size `N`. That is why you are getting an error.

Having said that, there are many efficient ways to solve your problem.

1. We can simply wrap your code in a list comprehension, like this

   ```
   def generateList(n):
       return [randint(1, 9) for i in range(n)]
   ```
2. Use [`randrange`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randrange) instead of [`randint`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.randint), like this

   ```
   def generateList(n):
       return [randrange(1, 10) for i in range(n)]
   ```
3. If the number of possible elements is small, you can even use [`choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice) like this

   ```
   def generateList(n, sample_space = range(1, 10)):
       return [choice(sample_space) for i in range(n)]
   ```

**Note:** Since `n` is going to large, if you are using Python 2.7, use `xrange` instead of `range`. You can read more about the differences in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23221025/1903116).

Answer (score 5):

No, there is not a function specifically dedicated to this task.  But you can use a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) if you want to condense the code:

```
def generateList(n):
    return [randint(1, 9) for _ in range(n)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to just have to sample it n times, each with size 1.  The reason you are running into the error is that sample doesn't want to repeat numbers:  when you ask for 12 unique numbers from a 10 element list, it chokes.  Try:

```
def generateList(n, theList):
    return [random.sample(theList, 1) for _ in range(n)]
```