# how can i make a list from 1 to a certain number

Tags: python

how can i make a list of number form 1 to a certain number?
i want to make a script that can do things like below:

```
number=20
list=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
```

i don't know how do make this happens.
is there certain function for auto produce the list, i am now typing it manually?
i've try to google it, but most the answers are about seperating a number and make a list.like this

```
a='1234'
a.split(' ')
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: look at `range()` function

Comment: Use `range(1,given_number)`

Comment: `[n for n in range(1,21)]` will give you your list

Comment: Use `range`. E.g `range(20) = [0, 1, 2, ..., 18, 19]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a list of consecutive numbers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558007/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-consecutive-numbers) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265935/python-create-list-with-numbers-between-2-values. Google your question first

Answer (score 1):

For Python 2,

```
l = range(1, number + 1)
```

In Python 3, `range` returns an iterable sequence so if you really need a list, you can convert it

```
l = list(range(1, number + 1))
```

Comment: A Python 3 range object is not an iterator, you can't call next() on it

Comment: Thanks for the correction.