# How to fill a list in a single line with n integers?

Tags: python

I want to fill a list with n integers in a single line, I tried this but how to add a limit of n?

```
L=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
```

Comment: `[k for k in in range(n)]` ?

Comment: One-liners aren’t actually the way to do everything: use a for loop and with a counter so once the counter exceed that limit the loop breaks.

Comment: limit as max integer available or limit as numbers?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I generate a list of consecutive numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29558007/how-can-i-generate-a-list-of-consecutive-numbers)

Comment: here is the thing i want to fill a list with n integers but in a single line because i will send it for a problem submission on codeforces

Comment: Then what's wrong with the above line? Also that still doesn't explain why it ***has*** to e on one line...

Comment: I tried this:
n=int(input())
while True:
    L=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    if len(L)==n:
        break

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just slice at the limit.

```
limit = 3
L = [int(x) for x in input().split()][:limit]
```

Answer (score 2):

`zip` stops on the shortest sequence. You can use that to limit how many split items you consume.

```
limit = 5
L=[int(x) for _,x in zip(range(limit), input().split(maxsplit=limit))]
```

Comment: Great answer for what it's worth

Comment: The downvote is really a mystery as this is actually better than the other solutions because they create two lists... This only creates one in the exact right size (both `zip` and  `range` are iterators...)

Comment: adding `maxsplit=limit` to your code yields another 20x improvement on a 10MM int list.  Something like `[int(x) for _,x in zip(range(limit), input.split(maxsplit=limit))]` where `input= ' '.join(([str(x) for x in range(10000000)])`

Comment: @Chris = `[int(x) for x in "1 2 3 4 5 6".split(maxsplit=3)]` results in `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '4 5 6'`.

Comment: @Tomerikoo - right, and in other cases where the second thing in `zip` is a generator, it short circuits, so its a good general purpose solution.

Comment: @tdelaney don't need to preach the preacher, already got my +1 ;)

Comment: @tdelaney You have to use that in conjunction with your zip to terminate the process before the last unsplit digits

Comment: Still, regarding your last comment to me, check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862010/is-there-a-generator-version-of-string-split-in-python you ***can*** have a generator as the second argument to `zip` :D That would be minimal memory use on this page :)

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
n=int(input())
while True:
  L=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
  if len(L)==n:
     break
```

Comment: Why are you asking us? you should know... By the way if this is an online coding challenge, most chances are that you don't actually need to do this as the input will come in the expected format...