# How to create randomizer with python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Im pretty unexperienced and this is my first language so any pointers and tips will be gladly welcomed.

Im trying to create a raffle program where it asks how many participants are and with that maximum number draw out one winner.
I tried with:

```
import random
participants = int(input('How many participants?'))
list = [participants]
winner = random.choice(list)
print('Congratz {}, you are the winner!!!'.format(winner))
```

Comment: You are creating the list of numbers wrong. Have you tried printing out your list? See [How can I generate a list of consecutive numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29558007/2745495)

Comment: not required at all in this case as they indeed are consecutive numbers.

Comment: @DevLounge It's not required, but that's the problem with the OP's code, that there is no actual list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to create a list and then pick one of them. Just use a random integer between 1 and number of participants.

```
import random

participants = int(input('How many participants? :'))
winner = random.randint(1, participants + 1)
print(f'Congratz {winner}, you are the winner!!!')
```

Comment: i didnt knew the "randint" command, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

small modification of the code should do it:

```
import random
n_participants = int(input('How many participants?'))
winner = 1 + random.choice(range(n_participants))
print('Congratz {}, you are the winner!!!'.format(winner))
```

Comment: thanks. wont that "1+" cause trouble?

Comment: @antonimooo what  trouble would it cause