# Difference between itertools.product and loops

Tags: python, performance, loops, python-itertools

Is it better to use:

```
for i, j in itertools.product(range(3), range(3)):
    #code here
```

Or:

```
for i in range(3):
    for j in range(3):
        #code here
```

Sourcery.ai refactor recommends changing nested loops with `range()` to `itertools.product()`. Does it have better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be useful to use `itertools.product` if you want to avoid nesting for loops, or if you want to generate the cartesian product of some iterables. In that case, `itertools.product` could improve readability of code over nested for loops.

There is no practical advantage to using `itertools.product` over a nested for loop with `range` anymore with respect to memory consumption. A `range` in Python 3 uses constant memory, regardless of the size of the range it represents. It only needs to store the start, stop, and step values, and it generates the values needed to iterate over the loop lazily.

As far as runtime performance, I did a simple test, and the nested for loop using `range` seems to be faster than `itertools.product` in a tight loop:

```bash
>>> def loop():
...   for i in range(1000):
...     for j in range(1000):
...       pass
... 
>>> timeit.timeit(loop, number=300)
2.2965646009997727
>>> def itertools_product():
...   for i, j in itertools.product(range(1000), range(1000)):
...     pass
...
>>> timeit.timeit(itertools_product, number=300)
2.8750368439996237
```

Comment: *"There is no practical advantage to using itertools.product over a nested for loop with range anymore with respect to memory consumption"* - Why "anymore"? Was there ever?

Comment: @KellyBundy In Python 2 a `range` was eagerly evaluated to a list. See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23221025/does-range-really-create-lists

Comment: Yeah but `itertools.product` does that, too. (Well, not to lists but to tuples, but that takes about the same memory.)

Answer (score -1):

`itertools.product` and normal loops in Python are both used for generating combinations of elements from multiple input sequences, but they differ in terms of convenience, memory usage, and performance.

1. **Convenience**:

   - `itertools.product` is a Python library function that provides a simple and concise way to generate Cartesian product combinations. It eliminates the need for writing nested loops explicitly, making your code more readable and less error-prone.
   - Normal loops require you to write nested loops explicitly, which can be error-prone and harder to read, especially when dealing with multiple input sequences.
2. **Memory Usage**:

   - `itertools.product` generates combinations lazily, which means it doesn't create all combinations at once and stores them in memory. Instead, it generates each combination on-the-fly as you iterate over them. This can be memory-efficient when dealing with a large number of combinations.
   - Normal loops may require you to store all combinations in memory if you're building a list or other data structure to hold them, which can lead to high memory usage for large inputs.
3. **Performance**:

   - `itertools.product` is implemented in C and is highly optimized for performance. It can be faster than writing nested loops manually, especially for large input sequences.
   - Normal loops, while flexible, might not be as optimized as `itertools.product`, and their performance can depend on the specific way you implement them.

Here's a simple example to illustrate the difference:

Using `itertools.product`:

```py
    from itertools import product
    
    a = [1, 2]
    b = ['a', 'b']
    
    combinations = list(product(a, b))
    print(combinations)
```

Using normal loops:

```py
    a = [1, 2]
    b = ['a', 'b']
    
    combinations = []
    for x in a:
        for y in b:
            combinations.append((x, y))
    
    print(combinations)
```

Both approaches will give you the same result, but the code using `itertools.product` is more concise and memory-efficient, especially when dealing with larger input sequences. Therefore, `itertools.product` is often preferred for tasks involving Cartesian products or combinations of multiple input sequences.

Comment: Can you explain why itertools needs less memory? In the example you gave they're pretty much identical.

Comment: Actually that isn't true - itertools uses slightly **more** memory because it duplicates `a` and `b` when it starts.