# Understanding of @gen.coroutine annotation

Tags: python, tornado

I know that my question looks to broad, but I hope the answer on this question will give me correct direction what to read on. I am new to Tornado framework, basically I am new to Python.
I am looking into this [project](https://github.com/legnaleurc/telezombie):
Could you please explain me a few lines of code:

```
@gen.coroutine
def get_me(self):
    raise gen.Return((yield self._api.get_me()))
```

- What `@gen.coroutine` annotation is for?
- `raise` keyword is used for exceptions, isn't it? Why we use it here?
- Why we return everything in form of `generator`. Is the concept of Tornado framework to use generators. What is the reason?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `@gen` is a [decorator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), it will modify the function below it at definition.
- It uses `raise` to return values and will catch it with `except gen.Return` (I find it ugly but it works).
- Generators are a convinient way to avoid memory usage and allow [lazy programing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20535379/6362697), always try [to return a generator over an iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/231855/6362697).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I found out documentation for `gen.Return`. """Special exception to return a value from a `coroutine`.
    If this exception is raised, its value argument is used as the
    result of the coroutine::
           `raise gen.Return(json_decode(response.body))`
    In Python 3.3, this exception is no longer necessary: the ``return``
    statement can be used directly to return a value (previously
    ``yield`` and ``return`` with a value could not be combined in the
    same function).
    """

Answer (score 4):

Following the Tornado documentation, I found that the general way to ensure async behavior is by the use of **event loop** and **callback functions**. 
But using callbacks is syntactically difficult and kind of confusing. 
So the developers of tornado came up with the use of decorators(just like flask,cherrypy etc).

- When you follow the source code of Tornado, you will see `gen.py` module under which they define the coroutine decorator. It's really an elegant way to ensure concurrency in Tornado.
- The `raise` is to handle exception. I find it quite easy as it simply returns `except gen.Return`.
- Tornado use `generators` simply it's easy to use.