# Python: encapsulation in frequently called function

Tags: python, performance, encapsulation

I have this Python 3 pseudo-code:

```
def f1():
    a, b, c, d, e, f = some_other_fn()
    if (condition):
        f2(a, b, c, d, e, f)

def f2(a, b, c, d, e, f):
    complex_set_of_operations_with(a, b, c, d, e, f)

for i in range(1000):
    f(1)
```

Now, I am kind of annoyed at the long signature and repetition in `f2()` and would like to encapsulate that into `f1()`:

```
def f1():
    def f2():
        complex_set_of_operations_with(a, b, c, d, e, f)

    a, b, c, d, e, f = some_other_fn()
    if (condition):
        f2()

for i in range(1000):
    f(1)
```

Now, my question is: if I run `f1()` a thousand times, does the interpreter have to parse `f2()` a thousand times or is it smart enough to create a reusable reference?

Comment: why not `def f2(*args): complex_set_of_operations_with(*args)`

Comment: Do you call `f2` recursively, or in more than one place in `f1`? If not, you could just drop `f2` entirely and inline it's code into `f1`.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: I have to use `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, `e`, and `f` individually different places within `f2()` and I find it more readable to have them declared explicitly.

Comment: @tobias_k I call it only in `f1` that is also why I want to encapsulate it. I could inline it, but I like to keep the operational code separate from the conditions that trigger it. It's mostly a style and readability question—and admittedly, with some academic curiosity added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's have a look (using Python 3.5 that I happen to have at hand). We will use the [dis](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html) module to disassemble the function and inspect its bytecode:

```
>>> def f1():
...     def f2():
...         complex_set_of_operations_with(a, b, c, d, e, f)
...     a, b, c, d, e, f = some_other_fn()
...     if (condition):
...         f2()
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f1)
  2           0 LOAD_CLOSURE             0 (a)
              3 LOAD_CLOSURE             1 (b)
              6 LOAD_CLOSURE             2 (c)
              9 LOAD_CLOSURE             3 (d)
             12 LOAD_CLOSURE             4 (e)
             15 LOAD_CLOSURE             5 (f)
             18 BUILD_TUPLE              6
             21 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object f2 at 0x7f5d58589e40, file "<stdin>", line 2>)
             24 LOAD_CONST               2 ('f1.<locals>.f2')
             27 MAKE_CLOSURE             0
             30 STORE_FAST               0 (f2)
             ...  # the rest is omitted for brevity
```

In runtime, the Python interpreter interprets these primitive bytecode instructions one by one. These instructions are explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/dis.html#bytecodes).

As the last four instructions from the example above suggest, Python indeed builds the internal function every time (and stores it under the name `f2`), but it appears to do so efficiently by loading a pre-compiled constant *code object* of `f2` (the `21 LOAD_CONST`) line, i.e. it does not compile the `f2`'s body over and over again.

Comment: Excellent insight. Thanks. I am also using 3.5 by the way, so this fits like a glove.

Answer (score -2):

Python evaluation is lazy. It will only be evaluated when it's actually needed.

https://swizec.com/blog/python-and-lazy-evaluation/swizec/5148

[Lazy evaluation python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535342/lazy-evaluation-python)

Comment: Does this answer the question? OP was not asking whether `f2` will be evaluated before `f1` is being run, but whether it's evaluated _again_ each time `f1` runs. Also, both the blog post and the linked answer are about generators, which is something entirely different.