# Find index of largest element and value at a particular index in a python map object without casting it into a list or other such structures

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have a task where I need to do some operations over a map object. Most of them are very fast as they can be done as lambda functions over the map. The map starts of as containing a bunch of lists. I use a lambda function to drop the first `k` elements from each individual list and that takes around `0.00017` seconds according to my benchmarking. I then use a lambda function to multiply the values in each list in the map which takes `0.00014` seconds.

So my map finally contains float values, I now want to find the position of the largest value in the map as well as the value at a certain fixed position. It is trivial to do this by casting it into a list but I do not want that as in my benchmarking doing a `list(map_object)` takes around 1 second. The subsequent operations are ofcourse cheap but this becomes a bottleneck for me. Is there a way to find these 2 values directly without any sort of casting?

My code

```
tokenized_base_prompt = tokenizer.convert_ids_to_tokens(tokenizer.encode(base_prompt))
length_of_base_prompt = len(tokenized_base_prompt)

s_time = time.time()
# remove first length_of_base_prompt tokens from each the map t
t = map(lambda x: x[length_of_base_prompt:], t)
e_time = time.time()
print("Time taken: ", e_time - s_time)

s_time = time.time()
# each element in t is a list of probabilities. Multiply them to get the final probability
t = map(lambda x: np.prod(x), t)
e_time = time.time()
print("Time taken: ", e_time - s_time)

s_time = time.time()
k = 10
# find value at kth position in the map t
ls = list(t)
kth_value = ls[k]
max_value_idx = np.argmax(ls)
e_time = time.time()
print("Time taken: ", e_time - s_time)
```

Output:

```
Time taken:  0.00017833709716796875
Time taken:  0.00014710426330566406
Time taken:  1.0032751560211182
```

To get an idea of what `t` looks like, here is what would be printed if I decided to print it before the list cast -

Code -

```
(Prev Code)
s_time = time.time()
# each element in t is a list of probabilities. Multiply them to get the final probability
t = map(lambda x: np.prod(x), t)
e_time = time.time()
print("Time taken: ", e_time - s_time)

for i in t:
    print(i)
```

Output -

```
3.850080530341006e-05
3.6351866579458384e-05
2.891034283156803e-06
8.263684668437109e-06
2.821185942978527e-06
7.2906073530389474e-06
...
9.754352384190414e-06
4.590878965851996e-06
```

Note: Incase it helps the size of the map object is always <= 200 but I would prefer to have a way which does not care about the size

Comment: You forgot to post your code [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: In addition to telling us what your code does, _show_ us your code

Comment: @JonSG no like output of a map call

Comment: @pho Added a MRE

Comment: Can you provide an example of `t`?

Comment: Note, `map()` returns a generator that will "eventually" yield results. `foo = map(fn, bar)` does almost nothing until `foo` is iterated over.

Comment: Your MRE doesn't define `t` to begin with, but all your time calculations except the last one are irrelevant. `map` returns a generator object that doesn't evaluate its elements until they are requested ([lazy evaluation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535342/lazy-evaluation-in-python)), so just defining `t = map(...)` does (next to) no work. The part that actually requires work, i.e. evaluating the elements of the map, evidently takes time

Comment: Added an example for how `t` looks like

Comment: @pho Is there a way to make this more optimized then?

Comment: _"Is there a way to make this more optimized"_ would depend on the original contents of `t`. The first `map` you've shown removes the first `length_of_base_prompt` of each element of that `t`. If `t` is a 2D array, you could just do `t[:, length_of_base_prompt:]`

Comment: From there, [`np.prod`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.prod.html) and [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) take an `axis` argument that allow you to apply the function to each row of the array

Comment: do you actively want to modify `t` or is that just a byproduct of your attempt?

Comment: @pho `t` is actually a generator object before the first function. I use this function (https://opennmt.net/CTranslate2/python/ctranslate2.Generator.html#ctranslate2.Generator.score_iterable) on a bunch of data which returns a `Iterable[ScoringResult]` object, essentially a generator. I process it using `map(lambda x: np.exp(x.log_probs), result)` which gives me t

Comment: @JonSG I don't really need to preserve `t` or anything, I'm only concerned about the final value

Comment: Generically, `max_idx, max_val = max(enumerate(my_map_obj), key=lambda t:t[1])` will give you the max value and its index. But ultimately you do have to iterate all the way through the map object: you can't know which element is the maximum until you've looked at all of them (unless you know something about the data which lets you rule out some elements without checking them).

Answer (score 0):

These approaches seem to have the same performance. Anyone who has a better approach should feel free to dovetail.

```py
import timeit
import random
import numpy

def test1(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest):
    t2 = [numpy.prod(row[length_of_base_prompt:]) for row in t]
    return t2[index_of_interest], numpy.argmax(t2)

def test2(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest):
    max_value = None
    for index, row in enumerate(t):
        value = numpy.prod(row[length_of_base_prompt:])

        if max_value is None or max_value < value:
            max_value = value
            index_of_max = index

        if index == index_of_interest:
            value_at_index = value
    return value_at_index, index_of_max

def test3(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest):
    t = map(lambda x: x[length_of_base_prompt:], t)
    t = map(lambda x: numpy.prod(x), t)
    t = list(t)
    value_at_index = t[index_of_interest]
    index_of_max = numpy.argmax(t)
    return value_at_index, index_of_max

rows_in_t = 200
items_in_rows_of_t = 200
t = [
    [random.random() for _ in range(items_in_rows_of_t)]
    for _ in range(rows_in_t)
]

length_of_base_prompt = 5
index_of_interest = 10

result1 = test1(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest)
result2 = test2(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest)
result3 = test3(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest)
print(result1 == result2 and result1 == result3)

number_of_runs = 1_000
print(timeit.timeit("test1(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest)", globals=globals(), number=number_of_runs))
print(timeit.timeit("test2(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest)", globals=globals(), number=number_of_runs))
print(timeit.timeit("test3(t, length_of_base_prompt, index_of_interest)", globals=globals(), number=number_of_runs))
```

giving result like:

```
True
3.1786246999399737
3.2922821999527514
3.484593900036998
```